# HTML table sort in Javascript with Array works but why?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, sorting

In this code:

```js
let container = document.getElementById('variables');
Array.from(container.querySelectorAll('tr'))
  .sort((a, b) => a.getAttribute("name").localeCompare(b.getAttribute("name"), ))
  .forEach(tr => container.appendChild(tr));
```

```html
<table id="variables">
  <tr name=B>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr name=A>
    <td>A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr name=C>
    <td>C</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I create an unsorted HTML table and sort it with JavaScript.

I works but I do not understand why I do not get the original array followed by the sort one because the `forEach` do `appendChild` to the original table

What is the magic behind this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`foo.appendChild(bar)` puts `bar` at the end of `foo`.

Since an element can't exist in two places at the same time, if it was already the child of another element, it is removed from there first.

i.e. it is not the same as `foo.appendChild(bar.cloneNode(true))`

Comment: OK but in Array.from doc it is written that it creates a copy of the element. You say that it does not copy inside/childs elements?

Comment: @Benjamin — Array.from creates a **shallow** copy of the array-like object. References inside that array are still references to the original object.